# For a locally homeomorphic function, is the boundary of the image the image of the boundary?

Tags: general-topology

Given

- topological spaces $T$ and $U$,
- a locally homeomorphic continuous function $f$ from $T$ to $U$, and
- a set $X \subseteq T$,

is it always true that

$$f(∂X) = ∂f(X)?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - in fact this condition seems quite rare.

Take $U = \mathbb{R}$ and $T = (-1,1)$ equipped with the subspace topology, with $f \colon T \to U$ the inclusion map.  Take $X = T$.  $f$ is certainly a local homeomorphism - it is a homeomorphism onto its image.  The boundary of $X$ viewed as a subset of the space $T$ is empty, but the boundary of $f(X)$ is the two point set $\{-1, 1\}$.

More generally, any inclusion map $f \colon T \to U$ where $T$ is a subset of $U$ with nonempty boundary will do the job.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Follow-up question: what if $T = U$?

Comment: Still no: take $T = U = \mathbb{R}$ and let $f \colon T \to U$ be a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$, e.g. the sigmoid function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$.